# PL/SQL Procedure Char Parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, procedure

This is quite possibly a very stupid question but I've tried searching for and answer and come up empty.

I'm writing a procedure that takes a single parameter of type CHAR. i.e:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1 (Param1 CHAR(5))
  AS
  BEGIN
    ...
  END;
```

This doesn't work and throws an error around the CHAR(5) area. If I don't specify a size for the parameter, so just leave it as CHAR it works fine. I've tried including the keyword IN but this makes no difference.

Is there anyway of specifying a size for parameters in PL/SQL procedures?

Comment: btw general advice is not to use `char`. The standard string type is `varchar2`, or `clob` for huge values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Is there anyway of specifying a size for parameters in PL/SQL procedures?*

No, as documented in the manual

Quote from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#sthref1640

> For each parameter, you specify:
> -   Its name.
> -   Its parameter mode (...)
> -   Its datatype. **You specify only the type, not any length or precision constraints**

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you. I had looked at this page but must have skipped right over that. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

As a_horse_with_no_name mentioned before, you shoudn't specify parameters length in procedure definition.
However, if you want to control variable length, you can try this approach :

```
procedure A(var CHAR) is
 MAX_CHAR number := 10; -- for an instance
begin
 if length(var) > MAX_CHAR then
   -- here you can throw an exception
 end if;

 ...

end A;
```